# SQL Oracle Command "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle11g, qsqltablemodel, isqlquery

every time I want to create this table, it says Missing Right Parenthesis. Can someone please check what i have wrong please. Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE Pet
(
PetID Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OwnerID Char (7) NOT NULL,
TypeID Char integer NOT NULL,
PetName Char (30),
Description Char (50),
Birthday VarChar (255),
LastVisit VarChar (255)
);
```

Comment: What's "Char integer"?

Comment: Try commenting out lines to see which one is causing the problem. According to Oracle's site for 10g, you can use `/*` and `*/` to comment out lines. I'm assuming it's the same for 11g. If the table gets created with only one line commented out, you know which one is the problem. I would suggest commenting out the line for `OwnerID` first because it seems odd/incorrect.

Comment: Otávio Décio is right. TypeID Char integer NOT NULL, should be TypeID integer NOT NULL, OR (less likely given it's an ID) TypeID Char (<some int>) NOT NULL,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Pet 
(
PetID Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OwnerID Char (7) NOT NULL,
TypeID Char NOT NULL,
PetName Char (30),
Description Char (50),
Birthday VarChar (255),
LastVisit VarChar (255)
);
```

Check this column data type Char Or Integer - TypeID